# Generated RSpec controller test is failing with wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a brand new rails 6 application, and I installed rspec.

I created a controller, and when I run rspec I get this error:

> ```
> PagesController GET #index returns http success
>      Failure/Error: get :index
>
>      ActionView::Template::Error:
>        wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
>      # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>      # ------------------
>      # --- Caused by: ---
>      # ArgumentError:
>      #   wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
>      #   ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

The generated rspec test looks like:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CartController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end

end
```

Is there a bug in the generated code or is some other environmental issue the cause of this?

I don't see where there are 2 arguments anywhere?

Comment: Don't add controller specs to a new app. "Request specs provide a high-level alternative to controller specs. In fact, as of RSpec 3.5, both the Rails and RSpec teams discourage directly testing controllers in favor of functional tests like request specs."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35417#issuecomment-475723528) for Rails 6, upgrade to [rspec-rails 4.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-rails/versions/4.0.0.beta3):

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta3'
```

This is also referenced in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2086) for rspec-rails.

### Update from July 2021

This question generates pretty regular traffic and rspec-rails is now well past the 4.0.0beta3 version. (v5.0.1 as of today) Always check for the latest version at https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-rails and use that instead:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.0.1'
```

Comment: Thanks for keeping this up to date. The upgrade to Ruby 3 will hit this a lot.

Comment: I am using ruby 3 but still adding 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.0.1' doesn't solve the issue. @anothermh can you help with that?

Comment: Ruby 2.7 Rails 5.2 rspec-rails 5.1.1 and I just started seeing this error today - tests have not changed recently